# Problem with Org mode's export to markdown

Tags: org-mode, org-export, markdown

I'm trying to use Org mode's export to markdown, and am finding some unexpected results.

For a file:

```
* Section

This is some test.[fn:1]
@@markdown:This should appear in markdown export.@@

* Footnotes

[fn:1] This is a footnote.
```

The export backend produces:

```
# Table of Contents

1.  [Section](#org26628a6)


<a id="org26628a6"></a>

# Section

This is some test.<sup><a id="fnr.1" class="footref" href="#fn.1">1</a></sup>


# Footnotes

<sup><a id="fn.1" href="#fnr.1">1</a></sup> This is a footnote.
```

Which looks very much like a mixture of markdown with html markup. Plus `@@markdown: ...@@` does not seem to work.

What am I missing? Any ideas of how I could get better results?

**Update:** Says the Org mode manual:

> The `md` back-end is built over HTML back-end: any construct not supported by Markdown syntax (e.g., tables) will be controlled and translated by
>   ‘html’ back-end.

So that's probably the explanation to the result, as neither ToC nor footnotes seem to be supported by vanilla markdown.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want more flexibility in your markdown export you should look at [pandoc](https://pandoc.org) and [ox-pandoc](https://github.com/kawabata/ox-pandoc)

Comment: Thank you. I'm aware of `pandoc`, but things are definitely more convenient from within Emacs. As to `ox-pandoc` I experimented with it, but it broke my regular LaTeX export. I'm not sure why, perhaps I'm to blame. But as I installed it from MELPA, it brought Org mode 9 with it, while I have a repo installation with Org mode 8.2.

Comment: Hmm. Not sure why it would break your LaTeX export. Though pandoc/ox-pandoc uses its own template system for latex-pdf export. But in general I'd say use the newer Org if you can. You can also control pandoc directly with [pandoc-mode](https://github.com/joostkremers/pandoc-mode).

Comment: I also don't know why, but I'm sure it did. It converted `#+BEGIN_LATEX` to `\begin{LATEX}` and thus broke latex compilation. And it took me a good afternoon of debugging my setup to nail the culprit in `ox-pandoc`. I'll take a look at `pandoc-mode` though. Thanks again!

Comment: I must rectify something here regarding `ox-pandoc`. Apparently, the syntax `#+BEGIN_LATEX` no longer works for recent versions of Org mode, while `#+BEGIN_EXPORT latex` does. So, as I used the former in my document and `ox-pandoc` brought a recent version of Org mode with it, I ended up with an uncompilable document.